# Resetting round buttons in a loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, button, rounding

I have a few groups of round buttons defined in html which I reset as following inside my script:

```
$('input[name=innovationGrade1]').attr('checked',false);
$('input[name=innovationGrade2]').attr('checked',false);
$('input[name=innovationGrade3]').attr('checked',false);
$('input[name=innovationGrade4]').attr('checked',false);
```

This works perfectly, but does not look neat, so I tried to put it in a loop as following:

```
for (j = 1; j < 5; j++) {
  innovationGradeNumber="innovationGrade"+j;
  $('input[name=" + innovationGradeNumber +"]').attr('checked',false);
}
```

However, the loop does not work for me and does not throw any error. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `$('input[name=" + innovationGradeNumber +"]').attr('checked',false);`
with 
`$('input[name="' + innovationGradeNumber +'"]').attr('checked',false);`

You are using `string` not a variable value

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using jQuery you can use wildcard selection using this:

`$('input[name^="innovationGrade"]').attr('checked',false);`

This will select all input elements what start with 'innovationGrade'.